# Porque de Null Pointer Exception em programa simples de agenda em Java, e como configurar a função que retorna um array de telefones

Tags: java, funções, nullpointerexception

Boa noite! Estou tendo um problema com um trabalho da faculdade, que é aparentemente simples(porém, sou muito noob em Java, e não sei o que fazer!).

Gostaria que me ajudassem, estou recebendo Null Pointer Exception ao chamar o numero 3 do menu, após criar novos contatos. E também preciso de ajuda para codificar a função buscarTelefones, que tem um array como retorno(Não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer isso). Desde já, agradeço a compreensão e a ajuda de todos!

PS: Qualquer sugestão será bem-vinda[image: ![Foto do exercicio]

```
package agenda.de.telefones;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Controlador_AgendaDeTelefones {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Agenda agenda = new Agenda();
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true){

            System.out.println("1 - Incluir Contato");
            System.out.println("2 - Alterar Contato");
            System.out.println("3 - Alterar Telefone");
            System.out.println("4 - Buscar Contato");
            System.out.println("9 - Sair");

            int opcao = entrada.nextInt();

            switch(opcao){
                case 1: //Incluir contato
                    System.out.println("Voce escolheu: Incluir Contato!");
                    System.out.println("Digite o nome do contato: ");
                    String nome1 = entrada.next();
                    System.out.println("Digite o numero do contato: ");
                    String numero1 = entrada.next();
                    System.out.println("Digite o tipo de telefone: ");
                    String tipo1 = entrada.next();

                    Contato c = new Contato(nome1);                  
                    Telefone t = new Telefone(numero1, tipo1);

                    int status1 = agenda.novoContato(c, t);
                        if(status1 == 1){
                            System.out.println("Contato incluido com sucesso!");
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("O contato não pode ser incluso por falta de espaço");
                        }                      

                    break;
                case 2://Alterar Contato
                    System.out.println("Voce escolheu Alterar Contato!");
                    System.out.println("Digite o nome do contato a ser alterado: ");
                    String nome2 = entrada.next();
                    System.out.println("Digite o novo nome do contato: ");
                    String novoNome2 = entrada.next();

                    int status2 = agenda.alterarContato(nome2, novoNome2);
                    if(status2 == 1){
                            System.out.println("Contato alterado com sucesso!");
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("O contato não pode ser alterado!");
                        }         

                    break;
                case 3://Alterar Telefone
                    System.out.println("Voce escolheu Alterar Telefone!");
                    System.out.println("Digite o nome do contato que deseja alterar o telefone:");
                    String nome3 = entrada.next();
                    System.out.println("Digite o numero que deseja alterar: ");
                    String numero3 = entrada.next();
                    System.out.println("Digite o novo numero desejado: ");
                    String novoNumero3 = entrada.next();

                    int status3 = agenda.alterarTelefone(nome3, numero3, novoNumero3);
                    if(status3 == 1){
                            System.out.println("Contato alterado com sucesso!");
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("O contato não pode ser alterado!");
                        }         

                    break;
                case 4://Buscar Contato
                    System.out.println("Voce escolheu Buscar Contato!");
                    System.out.println("Digite o nome do contato que deseja buscar:");
                    String nome4 = entrada.next();

                    agenda.buscarContato(nome4);

                    //terminar                    
                    break;
                case 9:
                    System.exit(0);
                default:
                    System.out.println("Opcao Invalida! Tente outra vez.");
                    break;
            }            
        }     

    }    
}
```

Em seguida, tem as outras classes:

```
package agenda.de.telefones;

public class Agenda {
    private String dono;
    Contato contato = new Contato();
    Telefone telefone = new Telefone();

    private Contato[] meusContatos;
    private int numContatos;
    // controla a posiçao do array meusContatos

    private Telefone[] meusTelefones;
    private int numTelefones;
    // controla a posiçao do array meusTelefones

    //métodos construtores
    public Agenda(){
        meusContatos = new Contato[50];
        numContatos = 0;

        meusTelefones = new Telefone[50];
        numTelefones = 0;
    }

    //métodos de acesso
    public String getDono(){
        return dono;
    }

    public void setDono(String dono){
        this.dono = dono;
    }

    //métodos delegados
    public void mostrarDados(){

    }

    public int novoContato(Contato c1, Telefone t){        
        int retorno = 0;
        if(numContatos < 50){
            c1.associarTelefone(t);
            this.meusContatos[numContatos] = c1;
            numContatos++;
            numTelefones++;
            retorno = 1;
        }
        return retorno;
    }   

    public int alterarContato(String nome1, String novoNome1){        
        int retorno = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<numContatos; i++){           
            if(this.meusContatos[i].getNome().equals(nome1)){                
                meusContatos[i].setNome(novoNome1);
                retorno = 1;
            }
        }
        return retorno;
    }

    public int alterarTelefone(String nome3, String numero3, String novoNumero3){
        int retorno = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<numContatos; i++){            
            if(this.meusContatos[i].getNome().equals(nome3)){
                retorno = contato.alterarTelefone(numero3, novoNumero3, i);
            }
        }
    return retorno;
    }

    public void buscarContato(String nome4){
        for(int i = 0; i<numContatos; ++i){
            if(this.meusContatos[i].getNome().equals(nome4)){
                System.out.println("Numero: "+meusTelefones[i].getNumero());
            }
        }
    }

}

package agenda.de.telefones;

public class Contato {
    private String nome;
    private Telefone[] meusTelefones;
    private int numTelefones;
    // controla a posiçao do array meusTelefones

    //métodos construtores
    public Contato(){
        meusTelefones = new Telefone[50];
        numTelefones = 0;
    }

    public Contato(String nome){
        this.nome = nome;
        meusTelefones = new Telefone[50];
        numTelefones = 0;     
    }

    //métodos de acesso aos atributos (getters e setters)
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    //metodos delegados
    public void mostrarDados(){
        System.out.println("Nome: " + this.nome); 
    }

    public int alterarTelefone(String numero3, String novoNumero3, int i){    
        int retorno = 0;
        if(this.meusTelefones[i].getNumero().equals(numero3)){                    
            meusTelefones[i].setNumero(novoNumero3);
            retorno = 1;
        }
    return retorno;
    }

    public void associarTelefone(Telefone t){
        meusTelefones[numTelefones] = t;
        numTelefones++;
    }
/*
    public Array[Telefone] buscarTelefone(){
        Está comentado porque realmente não sei o que fazer :(
    }*/

}

package agenda.de.telefones;

public class Telefone {
    private String numero;
    private String tipo;    

    //métodos construtores
    public Telefone(){        
    }

    //métodos de acesso aos atributos (getters e setters)
    public Telefone(String numero1, String tipo1){
        this.numero = numero1;
        this.tipo = tipo1;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;        
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public void mostrarDados(){
        System.out.println("Numero: "+this.numero);
        System.out.println("Tipo: "+this.tipo);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código está um pouco bagunçado - e pra ser sincero, acho que o diagrama que passaram também está incompleto.

De qualquer modo, a dica que eu dou é que você tente separar bem a função de cada uma das classes.

Por exemplo: A classe Agenda não deveria, na minha opinião, criar um Telefone.

> O ideal é que a Agenda cuide apenas de objetos Contato, que por sua vez cuida de objetos Telefone.

Assim sendo, se você quiser um telefone de alguém, terá que chamar vários métodos em série, por exemplo:

```
    meusContatos[0]. // seleciona um objeto Contato (pos. 0 do Array)
        buscarTelefone()[0]. // retorna um objeto Telefone (da pos. 0 do Array)
            getNumero(); // retorna o número dentro desse objeto
```

Tem que lembrar que sua estrutura é assim, e não tentar "pular passos" na hora de fazer gets/sets dos dados.

> Eu *comecei* a modificar o seu código - ainda restam coisas a fazer, mas acho que dá para tirar uma idéia de como seguir.

---

**Classe Controlador:**

```
package agenda.de.telefones;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Controlador_AgendaDeTelefones {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Agenda agenda = new Agenda("nome");
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("1 - Incluir Contato");
            System.out.println("2 - Alterar Contato");
            System.out.println("3 - Alterar Telefone");
            System.out.println("4 - Buscar Contato");
            System.out.println("9 - Sair");

            int opcao = entrada.nextInt();

            switch (opcao) {
            case 1: // Incluir contato
                System.out.println("Voce escolheu: Incluir Contato!");
                System.out.println("Digite o nome do contato: ");
                String nome1 = entrada.next();
                System.out.println("Digite o numero do contato: ");
                String numero1 = entrada.next();
                System.out.println("Digite o tipo de telefone: ");
                String tipo1 = entrada.next();

                agenda.novoContato(nome1, numero1, tipo1);
                break;

            case 2:// Alterar Contato
                System.out.println("Voce escolheu Alterar Contato!");
                System.out.println("Digite o nome do contato a ser alterado: ");
                String nome2 = entrada.next();
                System.out.println("Digite o novo nome do contato: ");
                String novoNome2 = entrada.next();

                agenda.alterarContato(nome2, novoNome2);

                break;
            case 3:// Alterar Telefone
                System.out.println("Voce escolheu Alterar Telefone!");
                System.out.println("Digite o nome do contato que deseja alterar o telefone:");
                String nome3 = entrada.next();
                System.out.println("Digite o numero que deseja alterar: ");
                String numero3 = entrada.next();
                System.out.println("Digite o novo numero desejado: ");
                String novoNumero3 = entrada.next();

                agenda.alterarTelefone(nome3, numero3, novoNumero3);

                break;
            case 4:// Buscar Contato
                System.out.println("Voce escolheu Buscar Contato!");
                System.out.println("Digite o nome do contato que deseja buscar:");
                String nome4 = entrada.next();

                agenda.buscarContato(nome4);

                // terminar
                break;
            case 9:
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                System.out.println("Opcao Invalida! Tente outra vez.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Classe Agenda:**

```
package agenda.de.telefones;

public class Agenda {
    private String dono;
    private Contato[] meusContatos;
    private static int contador = 0;

    // métodos construtores
    public Agenda(String dono) {
        meusContatos = new Contato[50];
        this.dono = dono;
    }

    // métodos de acesso
    public String getDono() {
        return dono;
    }

    public void setDono(String dono) {
        this.dono = dono;
    }

    // métodos delegados
    public void mostrarDados() {
    }

    public void novoContato(String nome, String t, String tipo) {

        if (contador >= 50) {
            System.out.println("Não é possível adicionar mais contatos. Agenda cheia!");
            return;
        }

        meusContatos[contador++] = new Contato(nome, t, tipo);

    }

    public void alterarContato(String nome1, String novoNome1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++) {
            if (meusContatos[i].getNome().equals(nome1)) {
                meusContatos[i].setNome(novoNome1);
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Não foi possível alterar contato. Contato não encontrado!");
    }

    public void alterarTelefone(String nome3, String numero3, String novoNumero3) {
        /*
         * TODO
         */
    }

    public void buscarContato(String nome4) {

        for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++) {
            if (meusContatos[i].getNome().equals(nome4)) {

                System.out.println("Contato: " + meusContatos[i].getNome());
                System.out.println("Telefones:");
                for (int j = 0; j < meusContatos[i].getQtdTelefones(); j++) {
                    System.out.println(meusContatos[i].buscarTelefone()[j].getNumero());
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Contato não encontrado!");
    }
}
```

---

**Classe Contato:**

```
package agenda.de.telefones;

public class Contato {
    private String nome;
    private Telefone[] telefones = new Telefone[5];
    private int qtdTelefones = 0;

    // métodos construtores
    public Contato(String nome2, String t, String tipo) { // eles pedem int para
                                                            // telefone (?)
        this.nome = nome2;
        telefones[0] = new Telefone(t, tipo);
        qtdTelefones++;
    }

    // métodos de acesso aos atributos (getters e setters)
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    // metodos delegados
    public void mostrarDados() {
        System.out.println("Nome: " + this.nome);
        System.out.println("Telefones:");
        for (Telefone t : telefones) {
            t.mostrarDados();
        }
    }

    public void alterarTelefone(String numero3, String novoNumero3) {
        for (int i = 0; i < telefones.length; i++) {
            if (telefones[i].getNumero().equals(numero3)) {
                telefones[i].setNumero(novoNumero3);
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Não foi possível alterar, telefone não encontrado.");
    }

    public Telefone[] buscarTelefone() {
        return telefones;
    }

    public int getQtdTelefones() {
        return qtdTelefones;
    }

}
```

---

**Classe Telefone:**

```
package agenda.de.telefones;

public class Telefone {
    private String numero;
    private String tipo;

    // métodos de acesso aos atributos (getters e setters)
    public Telefone(String numero1, String tipo1) {
        this.numero = numero1;
        this.tipo = tipo1;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public void mostrarDados() {
        System.out.println("Numero: " + this.numero);
        System.out.println("Tipo: " + this.tipo);
    }
}
```

---

## Edit:

Aqui está o método `alterarTelefone`, da classe `Agenda`:

```
public void alterarTelefone(String nome3, String numero3,
                            String novoNumero3) {
    for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++) {
        if (meusContatos[i].getNome().equals(nome3)) {
            meusContatos[i].alterarTelefone(numero3, novoNumero3);
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Não foi possível alterar telefone. Contato não encontrado!");
}
```

> Ele busca por um `Contato` com esse nome, e quando ele encontra, ele chama o método `alterarTelefone` desse objeto.

---

Quanto ao método `buscarTelefone`, ele retorna um `array`, ou seja, vários telefones ao invés de um específico - o que significa que esse método é bem simples:

```
public Telefone[] buscarTelefone() {
    return telefones; // retorna nosso array inteiro
}
```

> **Veja na classe `Agenda` no método `buscarContato` como ele foi usado.**

(PS. Tinha um bug em `buscarContato` que tive que consertar.)

Answer (score 1):

A exceção `Null Pointer Exception` ocorre quando você tenta acessar uma referência que ao invés de estar apontando para um objeto, está com o valor Null.

Isso ocorre quando a variável é inicializada, não usamos `new` para criar o objeto a qual essa variável fará referência ou não atribuímos nenhum valor a ela(o padrão por default é Null) e depois tentamos acessar seu conteúdo. E quando se tenta acessar algo com valor igual a `Null` sempre resultará nessa exceção.

---

Quanto a sua segunda dúvida, para percorrer um array em java a maneira mais simples é usar um foreach.

Exemplo de foreach em Java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExemploForeach
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        lista.add("Banana");
        lista.add("Maçã");
        lista.add("Uva");
        lista.add("Kiwi");        
        lista.add("Pera");
        lista.add("Abacaxi");
        lista.add("Mamão");

        // FOREACH em JAVA
        for(String item : lista)
        {
            System.out.println("Minha salada de frutas tem " + item + "!");
        }        

    }

}
```

---

Segue exemplo modificado com um método (chama de função em programação estruturada e de método em orientação a objetos) retornando um ArrayList. Você deve especificar o tipo de retorno que o método terá na assinatura do mesmo.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExemploForeach
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        //Obs: Método não-estático não pode ser referenciado de contexto
        // estático, por isso dei um new pra criar um objeto dessa mesma
        // classe, mas poderia ter criado outra classe diferente

        ExemploForeach ef = new ExemploForeach();
        List<String> lista = ef.getLista();


        // FOREACH em JAVA
        for(String item : lista)
        {
            System.out.println("Minha salada de frutas tem " + item + "!");
        }        

    }

    public List<String> getLista()
    {

        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        lista.add("Banana");
        lista.add("Maçã");
        lista.add("Uva");
        lista.add("Kiwi");        
        lista.add("Pera");
        lista.add("Abacaxi");
        lista.add("Mamão");

        return lista;

    }

}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação e pelo exemplo de array com ArrayList, não sabia como usá-lo, e também não conhecia o foreach, muito bom!
Mas e para uma função retornar um array, bastaria eu fazer "return lista"(usando seu código de exemplo) ? Isso está correto ?
Novamente, Obrigado!

Comment: Isso que você disse e também especificar o tipo de retorno do método na assinatura do mesmo. Reparando que no exemplo eu usei uma classe executável e do main você não pode retornar nada porque a classe é estática e retorna void(vazo). Precisa criar outra classe que não seja executável, criar um objeto com o new chamar o método que retorna sua lista. A assinatura de um método que retorna um ArrayList pode ficar, por exemplo, assim: public List<String> getLista() {  ... } com retorno da lista no final como vc disse. Ver exemplo na resposta editada logo acima.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Trabalho foi apresentado, e seu comentário ajudou bastante em meu aprendizado. Valew! :)